# How to unit test App.OnStartup

Tags: wpf, unit-testing, mvvm

I'm writing a WPF application using MVVM, so I'm overriding OnStartup in App to set the View's ViewModel. Soon, at work, definition of done will include 100% code coverage so I'm trying to get in habit now at home on my own projects. I can't figure out how to test this function:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
  protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnStartup(e);

    ViewModel.MainViewModel vm = new ViewModel.MainViewModel();
    View.MainView v = new View.MainView();
    v.DataContext = vm;
    v.Show();
  }
}
```

Comment: you should avoid writing such functions in code. Before you go onto writing test cases. you should learn prism http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx. that works greatly with MVVM.

Comment: Well that's funny. I learned to do it that way from a video I saw from a guy that works at Microsoft.

Comment: He might want to show something not related to WPF frameworks.  Because for every POC you will not choose MVVM, Prism etc as it will make your presentation more complicated. If you follow prism, MVVM and WPF, rarely you will fall in such code scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

Nick, I would suggest that you feed this back to work. You've basically found a perfect example of why 100% coverage isn't usually a standard that most people adhere to. 
Personally I advise the companies I work for to be more pragmatic. There is a case of diminishing returns the further up the coverage % that you go, and certainly for UI applications you can save a lot of time by asking yourself, what will this actually test.

The code you have is going to show an application view window with a view model. You can use libraries such as [White](http://white.codeplex.com) or [WiPFlash](http://white.codeplex.com/site/search?query=Wipflash&ac=8) to provide easy ways of confirming this, but then all you have realy done is to confirm that windows has done its job. Later on you might be testign that clicking a button results in a value being displayed in a textbox and this has more value, but can be just as easily simulated by calling the ViewModel commands and checkign the view model state afterwards.

It is your choice, and I recommend trying both out, but these days I exclude my View namespace from all coverage counting.